# How to solve SonarQube complaints about my code?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'd like to know how to get rid of all non-alphabet in a string please.

I have a String s, where many non-alphabetical characters can be inside. For instance, space, dots, slashes, and any other crazy stuff that are not from a, b, c ... z and not from A, B, C ... Z.

I just want to retain those a, b, c ... z and A, B, C ... Z.

Hence, I wrote:

```
private static String getGoodString(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
}
```

This is actually working, quite happy.

However, SonarQube is complaining with:

> Refactor this code to use a "static final" Pattern.
>
> Replace these character ranges with Unicode-aware character classes.

How may I achieve the same (get ride of any non-alphabet), while making SonarQube very happy at the same time please?

Comment: You will have to live with it. There is no way to make SonarQube happy with your case until you tweak the [rule](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/rules/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this version:

```java
// inside your class
private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{Alpha}]");

private static String getGoodString(String s) {
    return p.matcher(s).replaceAll("");
}
```

Here I am using a static final `Pattern`.  Also, the regex `\p{Alpha}` is the Unicode version for matching any letter character.

Comment: `\p{Alpha}` is same as `[a-zA-Z]` e.g. for the string, `Häuser123!`, this code will output  `Huser` and not the expected string, `Häuser`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Please re-read the OP, in particular paying attention to the SonarQube complaints: `Replace these character ranges with Unicode-aware character classes.`

Comment: Yes, that's what I've mentioned in my comment . `\p{Alpha}` is the same as `[a-zA-Z]` and is not a Unicode-aware character class.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash The OP doesn't want a unicode-aware class, that is what SonarQube is suggesting, but that doesn't match their requirement. That `Häuser123!` should result in `Häuser` is a requirement you made up, as it doesn't follow from the question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Note that `\p{Alpha}` is the same as `[a-zA-Z]`; so, replacing `[a-zA-Z]` with `\p{Alpha}` does not serve any purpose except that it is another way to write the same thing.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash It might shut up SonarQube anyway because it is more clear and specific than [a-zA-Z], but even if it doesn't, breaking your own requirements just because a tool like SonarQube says so is an extremely bad idea.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - I do not have any problem if you are happy with this answer. However, `\p{Alpha}` is non-compliant. The documentation page, https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-5867 mentions it quite clearly.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash And I repeat: **`\p{Alpha}` is what the OP wants**, so if that is not sufficient to shut up Sonar, then the OP will need to add a suppression.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash No, because that wouldn't match only a-z and A-Z, and that is not what the OP wants. The requirements of the OP trump warnings from SonarQube.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - That's why I've mentioned that `\p{Alpha}` is the same as `[a-zA-Z]`; so, replacing `[a-zA-Z]` with `\p{Alpha}` does not serve any purpose except that it is another way to write the same thing. The correct answer would be: **you will have to live with it.**

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Then, as I said before, the OP has to add a suppression, e.g. using `@SuppressWarning` or `//NOSONAR`

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```java
private static final Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{Alpha}]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

private static String getGoodString(String s) {
    return regexPattern.matcher(s).replaceAll("");
}
```

```java
package com.company;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    private static final Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{Alpha}]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myPreferString = getGoodString("d35545.343\343C3.~&%@#43x");
        System.out.println("My prefer string: " + myPreferString);

        String myPreferStringOld = getGoodStringOld("d35545.343\343C3.~&%@#43x");
        System.out.println("My prefer string (oldway): " + myPreferStringOld);
    }

    private static String getGoodString(String s) {
        return regexPattern.matcher(s).replaceAll("");
    }

    private static String getGoodStringOld(String s) {
        return s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
    }
}
```

**(1)** https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-5867

> Unicode-aware versions of character classes should be preferred

**(2)** https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/regex/RSPEC-4248

> Regex patterns should not be created needlessly

**(3)** Javadoc

> ```
> /**
>  * Enables case-insensitive matching.
>  *
>  * <p> By default, case-insensitive matching assumes that only characters
>  * in the US-ASCII charset are being matched.  Unicode-aware
>  * case-insensitive matching can be enabled by specifying the {@link
>  * #UNICODE_CASE} flag in conjunction with this flag.
>  *
>  * <p> Case-insensitive matching can also be enabled via the embedded flag
>  * expression&nbsp;{@code (?i)}.
>  *
>  * <p> Specifying this flag may impose a slight performance penalty.  </p>
>  */
> public static final int CASE_INSENSITIVE = 0x02;
> ```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the answer @NVy, much appreciated.

Unfortunately, it now yields "Enable the "UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS" flag or use a Unicode-aware alternative."